# XCopy Error Handling in Batch File

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, xcopy

Trying to write a simple program that copies a file from one destination to another on multiple PC's and creates a log file for the PC's that were unsuccessful in doing the copy.

1) Read input from text file (contains list of PC ID's)
2) Copy file to required destination
3) If unsuccessful copy PC ID into a log file

So far I have the following:

```
FOR /F %%c IN (LIST.TXT) DO (
        XCOPY "%file_origin%" "\\%%c\%file_destination%"
        )
```

Comment: Check the errorlevel.  If it was unsuccessful the errorlevel will not be zero.

Comment: Add the following line after the `xcopy` statement: `if ErrorLevel 1 (> "\path\to\the\failure.log" echo %%c)`